# Printing list of list formating

Tags: list, python-3.x, format

Am fairly new to python programming.  Am trying to create a pattern from a given list of list. Here is my code:

```
NONE = ''

Column = 7
Rows = 6

def new_game_board() -> [[str]]:

   board = []

   for col in range(BOARD_COLUMNS):
      board.append([])
      for row in range(BOARD_ROWS):
         board[-1].append(NONE)
return board


gb = new_game_board()

for item in gb:
   print(item)
```

The board looks like this:

```
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Whereas, it should be like:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
*  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *  *
```

How can I format the list into the pattern above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Columns = 7
Rows = 6

def new_game_board() -> [[str]]:
   board = [ ''.join('%3i' % i for i in range(1, 1 + Columns))  ]
   board += Rows*[ Columns*'  *' ]
   return board

gb = new_game_board()

for item in gb:
   print(item)
```

This produces the output:

```
  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
  *  *  *  *  *  *  *
```

**ALTERNATIVELY:** Suppose we keep the existing new_game_board function (typos fixed) and add a printing function:

```
NONE = ''

Columns = 7
Rows = 6

def new_game_board() -> [[str]]:
   board = []
   for row in range(Rows):
       board.append([])
       for col in range(Columns):
           board[-1].append(NONE)
   return board

def print_board(board):
   print(''.join('%3i' % i for i in range(1, 1 + len(board[0]))))
   for item in board:
       print(''.join('%3s' % (v if v else '*') for v in item))

gb = new_game_board()
print_board(gb)
```

This produces the same output as above.

Comment: can we make this as a separate function, if we didn't want to change the new_game_board function. Instead if we wanted a separate function called print_board which just prints the board?

Answer (score 1):

If you make your board a class, you can define a `__str__` method to do this for you:

```
class Board(object):

    def __init__(self, r, c, val="*"):
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
        self.tiles = [[j+1 for j in range(c)]]
        self.tiles += [[val for j in range(c)] for i in range(r)] 

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(" ".join(str(c) for c in self.tiles[r])
                         for r in range(len(self.tiles)))
```

Now `print(Board(6, 7))` gives:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
* * * * * * *
```

This approach lets you have the list-of-lists behind the scenes but displayed in a user-friendly way, and also allows you to define common board game actions (e.g. "move piece from (r1, c1) to (r2, c2)") as instance methods.